# Are two optimization problems equivalent?

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete, decision-problems

In complexity theory. There are two optimization problems. If decision problems associted with them are all NPC, then we know the two decision problem are equivalent.  Are two optimization problems must equivalent?

For example, decision problems Corresponding to Minimum weight vertex cover problem and Maximum independent set problem are all NPC, hence the two decision problem are equivalent. However, are Minimum weight vertex cover problem and Maximum independent set problem equivalent？

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In your title "everAre wo" isn't understable for the layman I am (furthermore not completely fluent in colloquial English). The same for acronym $tow$ (which boat am I supposed to tow ?). Sorry for disliking SMS style... although I can guess NPC = Non Polynomial Complete.